# How to place 2 equations in 1 line in an align environment?

Tags: align

How do I properly place 2 equations in 1 line in an align environment? In the example below, equations 1, 2, and 3 are not properly centered. I would like them to be like equations 4, 5,  and 6 but without having to use 2 align environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \alpha_{s,j}^t = g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}) \quad \alpha_{s,j}^t = g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}) \\
    \alpha_{s,j}^t &= g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}) \\
   \alpha_{s,j}^t &= g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}})
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \alpha_{s,j}^t = g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}) \quad \alpha_{s,j}^t = g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}})
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    \alpha_{s,j}^t &= g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}) \\
    \alpha_{s,j}^t &= g(\frac{e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}}{\sum_j e^{\varphi_{s1}([h_j^t,l_j])}})
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Thank you but now how do I reference the equations?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
f: A \to B, g: B \to C \\
\begin{aligned}
f(a) &= \ldots \label{eq:f(a)} \\
g(b) &= \ldots \label{eq:g(b)}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}

\ref{eq:f(a)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centering first line of an align environment (Simulating \multicolumn{2}{c})](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67086/centering-first-line-of-an-align-environment-simulating-multicolumn2c) or does every of the equations need a number?

Comment: @cabohah how do i reference the equations? it seems that the aligned environment does not allow more than 1 label